# Netbeans 7.2 + Less plugin

Tags: css, plugins, netbeans, less, netbeans-7.2

I read this topic about a Less plugin for Netbeans: [Add syntax highlighting to .less-files in NetBeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3190029/add-syntax-highlighting-to-less-files-in-netbeans)

Anyone know a solution to version 7.2 of Netbeans without bugs? Adding a new file type is not the best solution because it displays several syntax errors.

Comment: I sent an email to the plugin module author asking if they would update this module for NB 7.2+. I will add details if I get a response.

Answer (score 4):

I'm using this plugin: http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/32782/lesscss-module.
Works fine for me (in 7.2).
*update:* new plugin version: http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/41315/lesscss-module

Since [Netbeans 7.4](http://wiki.netbeans.org/NetBeans_74_NewAndNoteworthy#Editing) less is supported by Netbeans without the need for an additional plugin.

Comment: I already tried, but have some bugs.  
And if you look at my post, you will see that I mentioned another topic that already has that link you passed.

Comment: There's an updated version compatible for NB 7.0+: http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/41315/lesscss-module

Comment: Works fine for me in 7.2.1. Any idea how to enable code folding?

Comment: Just installed this in 7.3. Any idea why I can't type comments in the format: /* comment */ ?

Answer (score 2):

LESS or SASS support *should* be added to 7.3 next version, maybe during 2013 summer.

source : http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=216509

This Less plugin doesn't work for me either, I switched to SublimeText2 for syntax support - coloring at least.

Comment: Just an update: LESS and SASS support is now added in the 7.4, currently in beta.

Answer (score 1):

LessCSS and SASS is being developed in 7.4. If you use Netbeans Dev Nightlies, you get it out of the box.

There are still bugs in LESS parsing but hey, this are in development right now.

Get it from http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/nightly/latest/start.html

It also includes less and sass compiling right after you edit. Not very advanced options, just "compile all files in this folder into this other one".

http://wiki.netbeans.org/NetBeans_74_NewAndNoteworthy